# split json string in sentences with esp32 not working with string variable datatype

Tags: c++, split

My goal is split a string with comes from a http requests from a webservice:
I have tested my code with a normal String variable and it seems to be working fine, the delimiter is a "\n":

see below:

```
String text = "First news\nSecond news 2\nAnother news 3\nAnother 4 news.\nLast news 5";

 const char* sz = text.c_str(); // get a pointer from string                        
 char *p = (char*)sz; // we need a no constant pointer for strtok_r
 char *sentence;

  while ((sentence = strtok_r(p, "\n", &p)) != NULL) { // delimiter is the \n

   Serial.println(sentence);
   
   delay(4);
 }
```

And obviously this code throws the next sentences in the serial monitor:

```
First news
Second news 2
Another news 3
Another 4 news
Last news 5
```

This is working fine because I set a string manually. But now when I do a http requests:

the content of the sentence is the same: "First news\nSecond news 2\nAnother news 3\nAnother 4 news.\nLast news 5"..

Now the code with provide me the sentence is this:

```
...       
DeserializationError error = deserializeJson(doc, payload);
                    
       //veify if the parsing was successfully
         if (!error) {
        // get the value of the property "news" from the json
        const char* news = doc[0]["news"];
    }
```

at this point, all looks nice, however this is not working properly, because I don't know, when the code try to print a splited sentence this throws all the sentence:
First news\nSecond news 2\nAnother news 3\nAnother 4 news.\nLast news 5 And not in segments, I don't know why it can't split, see my code below:

```
const char* news = doc[0]["news"];
String newsFromServer = String(news); 
const char* sz = newsFromServer.c_str();
char *p = (char*)sz; 
char *sentence;
 while ((sentence = strtok_r(p, "\n", &p)) != NULL) { // delimiter is the \n
    
     Serial.println(sentence);
       
    delay(4);
 }
```

this in the first iteration returns:

```
First news\nSecond news 2\nAnother news 3\nAnother 4 news.\nLast news 5
```

when should be:

```
First news
```

I don't kwno what to do, I have tried this:

```
char *sz = strdup(newsFromServer);

char *p = strdup(sz);
```

And doesnt work.

I would like to fix this guys, I hope your help. Remember that I need split this entire sentence in segments by using a "\n" delimiter. thanks so much.

Comment: If what you say is true, then the two strings are different.  What you should be doing is figuring out how the two strings are different.  I wonder if one of the strings contains the two characters `/n` instead of a single newline character.  Obviously, `strtok` will not treat a string differently because it came from a web service.

Comment: Check if the NLs in the JSON string are not escaped. If so, you must unescape them: `newsFromServer.replace("\\n", "\n");`

Comment: @zdf newsFromServer.replace("\\n", "\n"); definitely fixed this issue, The original json as we can see here: https://imgur.com/a/yHn0ZYL has \\n. Thanks so much.